# Does the Comm System add bonus every turn or just once?

Tags: battletech

I'm using this cockpit mod that adds bonus to morale. The thing is, does it add bonus every turn or just once when you land with your Mechs?

[image]

Comment: It seems to be each turn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It adds the bonus every turn. The ++ variant gives +3 morale/turn, which together with the base +2, is enough to fuel a called shot every other turn.